# Child is saved but parent_id is nil in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-attributes

Am I missing something about using accepts_nested_attributes_for with mongoid? I am trying to create a parent and child object with a has_many relationship using a nested form. The child object is saved, but the parent_id is null.

```
  def new
     @company = Company.new
   3.times { @company.invitations.build }
  end

private
def company_params
  params[:company].permit(:name, :slug, :invitations_attributes => [:recipient_email, :company_id])
end
```

Invitation Model

```
   belongs_to :company
```

Company Model

```
field :_id, type: String, default: ->{ slug }
field :name
field :slug
has_many :invitations
accepts_nested_attributes_for :invitations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:recipient_email].blank? }
```

The nested form

```
  <%= form_for @company do |f|%>

<%= f.label :name%>
<%= f.text_field :name%>

<%= f.label :slug%>
<%= f.text_field :slug%>




<%= f.label :invitations, "Invite Emails"%>
 <%= f.fields_for :invitations do |i| %>
  <%= i.email_field :recipient_email %>
 <% end %>


<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

From the logs

> {"insert"=>"invitations",
>   "documents"=>[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('587e88158a6818eb8f4bb64b'),
>   "recipient_email"=>"some-email@gmail.com", "company_id"=>nil,
>   "updated_at"=>2017-01-17 21:09:42 UTC, "created_at"=>2017-01-17
>   21:09:42 UTC}

Comment: your `create` action?

Comment: Try removing `:company_id` from inside permitted attributes -> `:invitation_attributes`.